# Doest TensorFlow 2 supports Multiprocessing on different CPU cores?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am stuck in implementing the Asynchronous Advantage Actor-Critic (A3C) using TensorFlow 2.

**Problem Definition:**
For A3C implementation, I have to create a bunch of workers (as much as number of CPU cores) and a master. All the workers and also the master will create a copy of a unique CNN module for themselves. The problem arises when each worker has to optimize the master's CNN module and also synchronize its weight with the weights of the master's CNN. I have implemented this by multithreading with no problems, but when multiprocessing comes in, python could serialize neither the weights nor CNN itself to pass between workers and master.

**Other's problem:**
When I was googling to cope with this problem I have noticed different opinions (Also almost all the Q-A were related to the TF 1). Some people believe that TensorFlow doesn't support multiprocessing so they either moved to PyTorch or just used multithreading. Other people proposed [ray library](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/auto_examples/plot_example-a3c.html).

First of all, I want to know is it possible to do a multiprocessing approach like A3C by TF 2.
And if it is possible I will appreciate it if someone shares similar works with me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the exact same issue myself. I did find a resource (see link below) that uses TF1.X and `multiprocessing` for A3C. In general, they use Queues to share the model weights.

Personally, I'm curious is there's an easier or better way to use `multiprocessing` for A3C. I found it quite hard to replicate their approach, so if you find another method, please share!

https://github.com/hongzimao/a3c/blob/master/train.py